# How to make nested transclusion in angular work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I cannot make nested transclusion work.

There are two directives, both of which declare they will transclude their content. When I nest them, the inner doesn't have any content.

Here is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c7UvM/3/) fiddle, that demonstrates my problem.

Here is the code:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.text = 'Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor...';
}

angular.module('transclude', [])
 .directive('outer', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: {},
      template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
                '<div>Outer</div>' +
                '<inner ng-transclude></inner>' +
                '</div>'
    };
 }).directive('inner', function(){
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         transclude: true,
         replace: true,
         template :'<div style="border: 1px solid red;">' +
                   '<div>Inner</div>' +
                   '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                   '</div>'
     };
 });
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should ng-transculde inside the inner directive since transclude replaces the inner html

```
angular.module('transclude', []).directive('outer', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
            '<div>Outer</div>' +
            '<inner><div ng-transclude></div></inner>' +
            '</div>'
        };
});
```

No change to inner directive needed.

I have updated the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c7UvM/5/)

Comment: Thanks. Now it seems obvious. :)

Comment: One thing to note is that this approach adds extra markup which, if you're doing a deep nesting, can get a bit messy. transclude:`element` avoids that.  But for your use either is probably good.

Comment: @KayakDave If we remove this extra markup inner html of outer div would not get transcluded whether you use `transclude:element`. Let me know if I am wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Yea, oops- I was thinking about a rather more complex and different scenario I had just been looking at.  For your situation, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, which can be useful in self contained components is displayed in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36gaz4ud/)

```
.directive('outer', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
                '<div>Outer</div>' +
                '<inner></inner>' +
                '</div>'
    };
 })
.directive('inner', function(){
     return {
         restrict: 'E',
         replace: true,
         require: '^outer',
         template :'<div style="border: 1px solid red;">' +
                   '<div>Inner</div>' +
                   '<div ng-transclude></div>' +
                   '</div>'
     };
 });
```

This will pass the `transclude: true` down the dom tree to the inner directive.

The downside of this is that the  cannot be used by itself and in the jsfiddle it throws an [ngTransclude: Orphan Directive Error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngTransclude/orphan?p0=%3Cdiv%20ng-transclude%3D%22%22%3E)

Because of this I require that the `inner` directive be a child of the `outer` directive, that way it will always have the transclusion passed down to it.

This is really nice to break up large directives into smaller ones.